# Eight Queens Algorithm for Different Starting Points

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to find a solution to the Eight Queens problem regardless of the starting point. Below is my Solver class, however it doesn't work for some reason when I place the queen in a row other than the first one.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Queens {
  private static int x;
  private static int y;
  private static ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  public Queens(int index, int row, int pos) {

    for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
      rows.add(i);
    rows.remove(row);
    x = pos;
    y = row;
  }

public static boolean solve(int row, int[][] board, int N, int pos) {
    board[y][x] = 1;
    System.out.println("row: " + row);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if(board[i][j]==1) System.out.print("Q ");
        else System.out.print("* ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();    
    if(row>=N-1) return true;
    for(int position = pos; position < N; position++) {
      if(isValid(board, rows.get(row), position, N)) {
        board[rows.get(row)][position] = 1;
        if(!solve(row+1, board, N, 0)) {
          board[rows.get(row)][position] = 0;
        } else
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static boolean isValid(int[][] board, int y, int x, int N) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
      if(board[i][x]==1)
        return false;
    i = y - 1;
    j = x - 1;
    while((i>=0)&&(j>=0))
      if(board[i--][j--]==1) return false;
    i = y - 1;
    j = x + 1;
    while((i>=0)&&(j<N))
      if(board[i--][j++]==1) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

For example, when I place the initial queen on board[2][2], this is the solution I get:

```
Q * * * * * * * 
* * Q * * * * * 
* * Q * * * * * 
* * * * * Q * * 
* * * * * * * Q 
* Q * * * * * * 
* * * Q * * * * 
* * * * * * Q *
```

What is wrong with the code?  Why does it disregard the initial piece? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your debugging attempt?  Insert print statements in strategic locations to trace the control and data flow.  Dig down to a specific problem.  Describe it and post the detailed output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the bounds for the for loop in isValid? Do they prevent you from placing a queen into a column where there's another queen below?

A similar question applies also to the while loops -- can they detect that there's a queen on the diagonal but *below* the one you're placing now?

Comment: Yes, I realized the below problem and solved it, but forgot to update. Basically I needed two more while conditions that scanned the below diagonals. Thanks anyways.